# Xdebug doesn't work with Laravel Sail and PHP 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug

Xdebug doesn't work for me. Could not connect to debugging client.

- Sail Version: 1.13.1
- Laravel Version: 8.82.0
- PHP Version: 8.1.1
- OS: macOS 12.2

Steps To Reproduce:

1. Add to the .env file:

```
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
```

2. Rebuild application's containers
3. Run an Artisan command with Xdebug

```
sail debug migrate
```

and...

`Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client`

Regards! :)

Comment: So how is your debug client (VSCode, PhpStorm or whatever you have got there) looks like? Does it listen on Xdebug port?

Comment: did you solve this? i am experiencing the same issue